# Call variable as parameter in batch script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that sets up a project for a user. There is one part that only has to be done once. I was thinking of wrapping the entire script in an If statement that checks to see if an environment variable exits.

```
 if [ "$VAR" = "" ]; then

  do the part that only need to be set up once
  export VAR="yes"

  else

  do the rest of the build

fi
```

The script doesn't seem to recognize that the VAR has a value in it and it always runs the first statement.

Comment: That `export` is only going to set the value for *that single run* of the script. The next time (and in the shell session that ran that script) that variable will go back to being unset. If you need that variable to persist you need to include it in the user's session startup files/etc. or use some other indication of completeness (like a stamp file, etc.).

Comment: To make `VAR` persistent, you need to _source_ the script instead of _executing_ it.   From the command line, run `source myscript.sh` (replace myscript.sh with whatever is the file name of your script.)

Comment: Is a stamp file just an empty file saved when the command is run? @EtanReisner

Comment: That's the normal form, yes. But it can contain any relevant information you want it to contain if that's more helpful.